# Heroku: slug size too large after installing Pytorch

Tags: python, heroku, pytorch

I've been getting the slug size too large warning (`Compiled slug size: 789.8M is too large (max is 500M)`) from Heroku and I can't figure out why, as my model size (cnn.pth below) is fairly small and my file directory is only 1.1mb in total: [screenshot of directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YJoW.png)

It seems like the size increase is caused by running `pipenv install torch`, as the slug size was 89.1mb before installing `torch` and 798.8mb after.

My Pipfile currently has these packages installed:

```
[packages]
flask = "*"
flask-sqlalchemy = "*"
psycopg2 = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"
requests = "*"
numpy = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
pillow = "*"
torch = "*"
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Edit: I'm running Mac OSX 10.10.5, using `Flask` and `pipenv`.

Answer (score 22):

The pytorch package that you're installing comes with both cpu and gpu support, thus has a large size. It seems you're using the free version of heroku, and only require the cpu support. The solution is to install the pytorch package for cpu only i.e.

In `requirements.txt`, write the wheel file path corresponding to the version of pytorch (cpu) that you're interested in. You can find the [list of wheel files](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html), which can be installed with `pip`. For example, for PyTorch 1.3.1, torchvision 0.4.2, Python 3.7, Linux, you can write the following for pytorch and torchvision respectively:

```py
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.3.1%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torchvision-0.4.2%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

The above will download `torch-1.3.1+cpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl` (107MB) `torchvision-0.4.2+cpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl` (13MB) respectively.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried this but it didn't work. I realised I didn't mention my OS in my original question - I'm on Mac OSX 10.10.5. I've tried using the mac version `pipenv install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.3.1-cp37-none-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl` (from the link you shared) but it returned me this error: `torch-1.3.1-cp37-none-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`.

Comment: I wonder if the issue might be because I'm using `pipenv install` instead of `pip install`? I found [this solution](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2394) while searching, but found their answer rather confusing, and haven't been able to get it to work (I changed the name of the package in the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock).

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct python version and macosx version in wheel file as well. If it doesn't work, use the same `pip/pipenv install torch` to check the correct wheel (`.whl`) path which is printed while installation, and use the same path in your installation.

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a CPU only wheel file for OSX 10.10.5, the latest they support is presumably 10.7 (looking at the file name). I'm using Python 3.7.

Comment: I know it's late but that worked for me: `https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.3.1%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl`

Comment: yeah, it's because heroku is using linux, you don't need macosx wheel file. @zeniale for local installation, use macosx wheel, for heroku in requirements.txt, use linux one.

Comment: What if I have different Python versions in local development vs. deployment on Heroku? I locally have Py 3.8 and Heroku uses the newer Py 3.9. Wouldn't specifying fixed wheels break installation on either dev or deploy? More importantly, I'm developing on Windows vs. Heroku uses Linux.

Comment: Also, I get an error on Heroku: `ERROR: torch-1.8.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Answer (score 18):

1. Go to [PyTorch Get Started page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). Choose Stable version, Linux, pip, python, cpu and you can see:

```
pip install torch==1.8.1+cpu torchvision==0.9.1+cpu torchaudio==0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

2. Copy versions to your `requirements.txt`.

```
torch==1.8.1+cpu 
torchvision==0.9.1+cpu
```

3. And add to the beginning of the `requirements.txt` this:

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

After that, all packages will be installed on Heroku.

For reference:
`torch==1.8.1+cpu`  (169.1 MB);
`torchvision==0.9.1+cpu` (13.3 MB)

Comment: Just a hint: I tried this with `torch>=1.8.1+cpu` and it didn't work; the slug size was still too large. It seems to be important to use `==`, not `>=` in the requirements.

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.8.1+cpu (from -r /tmp/build_9027c8a3/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0)

Answer (score 3):

By today, March 28, 2022, these are the working versions:

```
torch==1.11.0+cpu
torchvision==0.12.0+cpu
```

Answer (score 1):

(Aug, 2, 2022) the only solution I found was leaving the requirements.txt like this:

```
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.11.0+cpu
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torchvision==0.12.0+cpu
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in `requirements.txt` (thanks to https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/47354#issuecomment-1003118847):

```
# Attempt to reduce slug size by discarding GPU-specific libraries
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html
torch==2.0.1
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html
torchvision==0.15.2
```

This reduces the wheel size from ~700MB to ~200MB

[image]