# Installing Python dependencies in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pip, pytorch, spacy

I wanted to make an Ai chatbot hosted on Heroku, but there are some problems with installing the requirements.

The chatbot needs the following packages:

1. discord
2. pytorch
3. spaCy

I already figured out putting discord into the `requirements.txt`, but I got no clue on how to do the other two dependencies.
The problem with them is that they aren't just installed with

`pip install NAME_OF_THE_PACKAGE` .

Pytorch for example needs:

```
pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu torchaudio==0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

and spaCy needs

`pip install -U spacy`

`pip install -U spacy-lookups-data`

`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`.

I tried different variations of the commands above, but none worked.
Now I even reached the built limit on my account.
Please help me if you know how to solve the problem.

Comment: You can use pytorch wheel file directly for heroku as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59122308/heroku-slug-size-too-large-after-installing-pytorch/59122860#59122860

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to create a requirements.txt file having all the dependency installed in your current environment. This will install

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

To download the Spacy Models, you can add this in the requirements.txt

```
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_trf-3.0.0a0/en_core_web_trf-3.0.0a0.tar.gz
```

For more info, go through this issue on Github

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1129

Comment: pip freeze installs all dependencies in your environment. I wouldn't recommend doing that if you're not in venv or something similar.

Comment: I was looking for an answer related to Spacy models. Thanks!