# Installing PyTorch with CUDA in setup.py

Tags: python, pytorch, setup.py, install-requires

I'm trying to specify PyTorch with CUDA in install_requires. The command to install with pip is

`pip install torch==1.8.0+cu111 torchvision==0.9.0+cu111 torchaudio===0.8.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

How do I do that in the setup.py install_requires?

Comment: You can specify the wheel file https://stackoverflow.com/a/59122860/6210807

Answer (score 4):

I also faced same problem later I fixed it but using this in `setup.py` files and it worked, just add these lines as in your `setup.py` file.

```
"torch@https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch-1.8.0%2Bcu111-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl",
"torchvision@https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torchvision-0.9.0%2Bcu111-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.wh",
"torchaudio@https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchaudio-0.8.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl"
```

All these are for linux version if you wantr any MACOSX or windows just change the link after @ in each line you can get link of your desired version from  https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Answer (score 0):

As of ([the just released](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v2.1.0)) PyTorch v2.1.0, you no longer have to specify the PyTorch CUDA-specific wheel (for Linux at least). If you can use CUDA 12.1, then you can just have `"torch >= 2.1.0"` as the dependency.