How do I have multiple src directories at the root of my python project with a setup.py and pip install -e?
I want to have two src dirs at the root of my project. The reason is that one is code I want to work without modifying any of the imports. The second is new code indepdent of the "old code". I want two src's with and pip install -e . to work. My setup.py is:
"""
python -c "print()"

refs:
    - setup tools: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#using-find-or-find-packages
    - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295885/how-does-one-install-pytorch-and-related-tools-from-within-the-setup-py-install
"""
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages
import os

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
with open(os.path.join(here, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='massive-evaporate-4-math',  # project name
    version='0.0.1',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    author='Me',
    author_email='me@gmail.com',
    python_requires='>=3.9',
    license='Apache 2.0',

    # ref: https://chat.openai.com/c/d0edae00-0eb2-4837-b492-df1d595b6cab
    # The `package_dir` parameter is a dictionary that maps package names to directories.
    # A key of an empty string represents the root package, and its corresponding value
    # is the directory containing the root package. Here, the root package is set to the
    # 'src' directory.
    #
    # The use of an empty string `''` as a key is significant. In the context of setuptools,
    # an empty string `''` denotes the root package of the project. It means that the
    # packages and modules located in the specified directory ('src' in this case) are
    # considered to be in the root of the package hierarchy. This is crucial for correctly
    # resolving package and module imports when the project is installed.
    #
    # By specifying `{'': 'src'}`, we are informing setuptools that the 'src' directory is
    # the location of the root package, and it should look in this directory to find the
    # Python packages and modules to be included in the distribution.
    package_dir={
            '': 'src_math_evaporate',
            'bm_evaporate': 'src_bm_evaporate', 
        },

    # The `packages` parameter lists all Python packages that should be included in the
    # distribution. A Python package is a way of organizing related Python modules into a
    # directory hierarchy. Any directory containing an __init__.py file is considered a
    # Python package.
    #
    # `find_packages('src')` is a convenience function provided by setuptools, which
    # automatically discovers and lists all packages in the specified 'src' directory.
    # This means it will include all directories in 'src' that contain an __init__.py file,
    # treating them as Python packages to be included in the distribution.
    #
    # By using `find_packages('src')`, we ensure that all valid Python packages inside the
    # 'src' directory, regardless of their depth in the directory hierarchy, are included
    # in the distribution, eliminating the need to manually list them. This is particularly
    # useful for projects with a large number of packages and subpackages, as it reduces
    # the risk of omitting packages from the distribution.
    packages=find_packages('src_math_evaporate') + find_packages('src_bm_evaporate'),
    # When using `pip install -e .`, the package is installed in 'editable' or 'develop' mode.
    # This means that changes to the source files immediately affect the installed package
    # without requiring a reinstall. This is extremely useful during development as it allows
    # for testing and iteration without the constant need for reinstallation.
    #
    # In 'editable' mode, the correct resolution of package and module locations is crucial.
    # The `package_dir` and `packages` configurations play a vital role in this. If the
    # `package_dir` is incorrectly set, or if a package is omitted from the `packages` list,
    # it can lead to ImportError due to Python not being able to locate the packages and
    # modules correctly.
    #
    # Therefore, when using `pip install -e .`, it is essential to ensure that `package_dir`
    # correctly maps to the root of the package hierarchy and that `packages` includes all
    # the necessary packages by using `find_packages`, especially when the project has a
    # complex structure with nested packages. This ensures that the Python interpreter can
    # correctly resolve imports and locate the source files, allowing for a smooth and
    # efficient development workflow.

    # for pytorch see doc string at the top of file
    install_requires=[
        'fire',
        'dill',
        'networkx>=2.5',
        'scipy',
        'scikit-learn',
        'lark-parser',
        'tensorboard',
        'pandas',
        'progressbar2',
        'requests',
        'aiohttp',
        'numpy',
        'plotly',
        'wandb',
        'matplotlib',
        # 'statsmodels'
        # 'statsmodels==0.12.2'
        # 'statsmodels==0.13.5'
        # - later check why we are not installing it...
        # 'seaborn'
        # 'nltk'
        'twine',

        # # mercury: https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/2747
        # 'dspy-ai',
        # # 'torch==2.1.2+cu118',  # 2.2 net supported due to vllm see: https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/2747
        # 'torch==2.2.2',  # 2.2 net supported due to vllm see: https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/2747
        # # 'torchvision',
        # # 'torchaudio',
        # # 'trl',
        # 'transformers',
        # 'accelerate',
        # # 'peft',
        # # 'datasets==2.18.0', 
        # 'datasets',  
        # 'evaluate', 
        # 'bitsandbytes',
        # # 'einops',
        # # 'vllm==0.4.0.post1', # my gold-ai-olympiad project uses 0.4.0.post1 ref: https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/2747

        # ampere
        'dspy-ai',
        # 'torch==2.1.2+cu118',  # 2.2 net supported due to vllm see: https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/2747
        'torch==2.1.2',  # 2.2 net supported due to vllm see: https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/2747
        # 'torchvision',
        # 'torchaudio',
        # 'trl',
        'transformers==4.39.2',
        'accelerate==0.29.2',
        # 'peft',
        # 'datasets==2.18.0', 
        'datasets==2.14.7',  
        'evaluate==0.4.1', 
        'bitsandbytes== 0.43.0',
        # 'einops',
        'vllm==0.4.0.post1', # my gold-ai-olympiad project uses 0.4.0.post1 ref: https://github.com/vllm-project/vllm/issues/2747
        # pip install -q -U google-generativeai

        "tqdm",
        "openai",
        "manifest-ml",
        'beautifulsoup4',
        # 'pandas',
        'cvxpy',
        # 'sklearn',The 'sklearn' PyPI package is deprecated, use 'scikit-learn' rather than 'sklearn' for pip commands.
        # 'scikit-learn',
        'snorkel',
        'snorkel-metal', 
        'tensorboardX',
        'pyyaml',
        'TexSoup',
    ]
)

and the errors I get in cli bash:
(math_evaporate) brando9@skampere1~/massive-evaporation-4-math $ tree src_math_evaporate/
src_math_evaporate/
└── math_evaporate_llm_direct.py

0 directories, 1 file
(math_evaporate) brando9@skampere1~/massive-evaporation-4-math $ tree src_bm_evaporate/
src_bm_evaporate/
├── configs.py
├── evaluate_profiler.py
├── evaluate_synthetic.py
├── evaluate_synthetic_utils.py
├── massive_evaporate_4_math.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── profiler.py
├── profiler_utils.py
├── prompts_math.py
├── prompts.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── configs.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── prompts.cpython-39.pyc
│   └── utils.cpython-39.pyc
├── run_profiler_maf.py
├── run_profiler_math_evaporate.py
├── run_profiler.py
├── run.sh
├── schema_identification.py
├── snap_cluster_setup.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── utils.py
└── weak_supervision
    ├── binary_deps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── make_pgm.py
    ├── methods.py
    ├── pgm.py
    ├── run_ws.py
    └── ws_utils.py

4 directories, 34 files
(math_evaporate) brando9@skampere1~/massive-evaporation-4-math $ pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/massive-evaporation-4-math
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating /tmp/user/22003/pip-pip-egg-info-bqrbfkt8/massive_evaporate_4_math.egg-info
      writing /tmp/user/22003/pip-pip-egg-info-bqrbfkt8/massive_evaporate_4_math.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /tmp/user/22003/pip-pip-egg-info-bqrbfkt8/massive_evaporate_4_math.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to /tmp/user/22003/pip-pip-egg-info-bqrbfkt8/massive_evaporate_4_math.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to /tmp/user/22003/pip-pip-egg-info-bqrbfkt8/massive_evaporate_4_math.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/tmp/user/22003/pip-pip-egg-info-bqrbfkt8/massive_evaporate_4_math.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      error: package directory 'src_math_evaporate/weak_supervision' does not exist
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

everything looks right to my. Why are the bugs happening?
I tried:
    package_dir={
            '': 'src_math_evaporate',
            'bm_evaporate': 'src_bm_evaporate', 
        },

to
    package_dir={
            'math_evaporate': 'src_math_evaporate',
            'bm_evaporate': 'src_bm_evaporate', 
        },

doesn't work. Both as root:
    package_dir={
            '': 'src_math_evaporate',
            '': 'src_bm_evaporate', 
        },

Don't know what else to try. What do I do?

The last example can't work, because dictionaries can't have duplicate identical keys.  The second one overwrites the first one.

What directories (and/or Python files) are meant to be the top-level import packages and under what name should they be importable? That is one of the most important questions. -- Also it would help greatly if you could reduce your question to a [mre] of what you are trying to achieve (remove all unnecessary details).

Also note that package_dir and editable installations are not compatible. Basically only the typical src-layout is allowed, but any other package_dir setting is very likely to not work for editable installation.

do the src folders need a __init__.py file?

The error message is correct, there is no 'src_math_evaporate/weak_supervision' subdirectory. To fix use
setup(
    name='massive-evaporate-4-math',
    version='0.0.1',
    package_dir={
        'math_evaporate': 'src_math_evaporate',
        'bm_evaporate': 'src_bm_evaporate',
    },
...
)

Don't use packages=... in setup.py. Setup is perfectly capable of finding all packages without explicit value for packages here.
Btw- though not required for the build/install, it would be better to add __init__.py files to all the package and module directories. With the current directory structure, submodules are hard to discover.

do the src folders need a __init__.py file?

why did you have the key and values match exactly in the package_dir? i.e., why is the src string missing?

For traditional, regular packages (as seen in most Python code) __init__.py files indicate that the directory is a Python package. See: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages
When a package is imported that __init__.py is implicitly executed. Makes it easy to pull in the names of subpackages (subdirs) or names of functions you want to expose, so you'll see those names when you run dir(my_package).

The key and values in package_dir in my example config do not exactly match up (the values have a src_ prefix) -- I just used the values from your directory structure. But the keys and values can be totally different. The keys are the packages names, the values are the source directories (relative to the root of the project) where those packages are found. More info: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

[Works] Let me demonstrate the packaging journey with two src directories without hindering the imports.
Project structure
.
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── pyproject.toml
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src_bm_evaporate
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── main.py
│   └── module2
│       └── main.py
└── src_math_evaporate
    ├── __init__.py
    └── random_string.py

Package Evaporate files
src_math_evaporate
__init__.py
from .random_string import generate_random_string


__all__ = ["generate_random_string"]

random_string.py
import random
from string import ascii_letters, digits


def generate_random_string(size: int = 32):
    choices = ascii_letters + digits
    return "".join([random.choice(choices) for _ in range(size)])


src_bm_evaporate
__init__.py
from .module1.main import generate_16_digit_random_str
from .module2.main import generate_8_digit_random_str


__all__ = [
    "generate_16_digit_random_str",
    "generate_8_digit_random_str"
]

module1/main.py
""" Both imports work. """
# from src_math_evaporate.random_string import generate_random_string
from src_math_evaporate.random_string import generate_random_string


def generate_16_digit_random_str():
    return generate_random_string(size=16)


module2/main.py
""" Both imports work. """
# from src_math_evaporate.random_string import generate_random_string
from src_math_evaporate import generate_random_string


def generate_8_digit_random_str():
    return generate_random_string(size=8)


Packaging files
MANIFEST.in
include setup.py
include MANIFEST.in
include README.md

graft src_math_evaporate
graft src_bm_evaporate

pyproject.toml
[build-system]
# These are the assumed default build requirements from pip:
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#pep-517-and-518-support
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

requirements.txt
-e .

setup.cfg
[metadata]
name = Evaporate
version = 1.0.0
url = 
license = 
description = ""
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
classifiers=
   Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only
   Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation


[options]
package_dir =
    bm_evaporate = src_bm_evaporate
    math_evaporate = src_math_evaporate
packages = find:
include_package_data = True

setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="Evaporate",
    version="1.0.0",
    packages=find_packages(where=["src_bm_evaporate", "src_math_evaporate"]),
)

Installing the project
$ Project via v3.9.6 (venv) on
❯ pip install -r requirements.txt 
Obtaining file:///path/to/Project (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... done
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Evaporate
  Building editable for Evaporate (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for Evaporate: filename=Evaporate-1.0.0-0.editable-py3-none-any.whl size=2663 sha256=776b86201258a51485a3a813ad3b77ed0f3084eff7f446c5aca5fc120475ea9c
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/tp/rpcspmx561bcqm4b82j43yym0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-eulzmur2/wheels/94/12/8f/da50fb6f83490ee21fe4e2791ad3320258060f4b4995742f2c
Successfully built Evaporate
Installing collected packages: Evaporate
Successfully installed Evaporate-1.0.0

I hope it helps.

@charlie-parker I put together a demo project and it is working fine with the configs for me. Please take a look at it and let me know if you need further assistance. Thanks for posting the question. I have wondered about doing this in the recent past. Now, I did it. Thanks to you.

Does this really work with editable installation? -- There is likely no need to have packages in both setup.py and setup.cfg. Is setup.py even necessary at all? Can it not be expressed in setup.cfg (or even pyproject.toml)?

@sinoroc, yes, with editable installation, it does work. Feel free to tweak and all. Thank you.

@sinoroc, if you remove the package_dir from setup.cfg and keep packages in setup.py, it should work just fine. and vice versa.

do the src folders need a __init__.py file?

@CharlieParker the __init__.py is not necessary, its just my way of packaging :)
