# How to setup.py my package that depends on PyTorch

Tags: python, installation, pytorch, setuptools

I am creating a Python package that depends on PyTorch. PyTorch's installation command is as follows (from https://pytorch.org/):

```
pip3 install torch==1.8.2+cu102 torchvision==0.9.2+cu102 torchaudio==0.8.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html
```

Question 1: How should I prepare setup.py?

I read this [Equivalent for `--find-links` in `setup.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689387/equivalent-for-find-links-in-setup-py) where it says we could add the link into `dependency_links` list, but this is no longer supported since 2019.

Question 2: How to programatically decide which version to install? (CPU, GPU, CUDA version)

The command above is for a GPU-enabled machine with CUDA 10.2. But if the machine doesn't have GPU, one would use:

```
pip3 install torch==1.8.2+cpu torchvision==0.9.2+cpu torchaudio==0.8.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html
```

Is it possible for my package's setup.py to automatically identify the user's system and modify the `install_requires` list accordingly?

Comment: Ask only 1 question at a time. -- First one is answered in the question you linked and that I answered. -- For the second one: it is not possible as far as I know. Basically I think I answered this already in the comments of my answer: document it clearly so that your users know what to do. There is nothing much you can do. Unless the situation has improved on Pytorch's side in the meantime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent for \`--find-links\` in \`setup.py\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689387/equivalent-for-find-links-in-setup-py)

Comment: This should answer your question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738473/installing-pytorch-with-cuda-in-setup-py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738473/installing-pytorch-with-cuda-in-setup-py)