# why Heroku: slug size so large after installing Pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku, pytorch

I'm trying to deploy python to heroku, but it's too big to deploy.
I've been getting the slug size too large warning (Compiled slug size: 789.8M is too large (max is 500M)) from Heroku
Compiled slug size: 826.6M is too large (max is 500M).
remote:  !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:

```
fastapi==0.78.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
numpy==1.22.4
opencv-python==4.5.4.58
Pillow==8.4.0
retina-face==0.0.12
uvicorn==0.17.6
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.11.0+cpu; python_full_version >= "3.6.2"
torchvision==0.12.0+cpu
tensorflow-cpu == 2.8.0
```

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.10.5
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.10.5
remote: -----> Installing pip 22.1.2, setuptools 60.10.0 and wheel 0.37.1
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
remote:        Collecting fastapi==0.78.0
remote:          Downloading fastapi-0.78.0-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
remote:        Collecting numpy==1.22.4
remote:          Downloading numpy-1.22.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (16.8 MB)
remote:        Collecting opencv-python==4.5.4.58
remote:          Downloading opencv_python-4.5.4.58-cp310-cp310-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (60.3 MB)
remote:        Collecting Pillow==8.4.0
remote:          Downloading Pillow-8.4.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.1 MB)
remote:        Collecting retina-face==0.0.12
remote:          Downloading retina_face-0.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
remote:        Collecting uvicorn==0.17.6
remote:          Downloading uvicorn-0.17.6-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
remote:        Collecting torch==1.11.0+cpu
remote:          Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.11.0%2Bcpu-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl (169.2 MB)
remote:        Collecting torchvision==0.12.0+cpu
remote:          Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torchvision-0.12.0%2Bcpu-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl (14.7 MB)
remote:        Collecting tensorflow-cpu==2.8.0
remote:          Downloading tensorflow_cpu-2.8.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (190.6 MB)
remote:        Collecting pydantic!=1.7,!=1.7.1,!=1.7.2,!=1.7.3,!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<2.0.0,>=1.6.2
remote:          Downloading pydantic-1.9.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting starlette==0.19.1
remote:          Downloading starlette-0.19.1-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
remote:        Collecting gdown>=3.10.1
remote:          Downloading gdown-4.4.0.tar.gz (14 kB)
remote:          Installing build dependencies: started
remote:          Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: started
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting tensorflow>=1.9.0
remote:          Downloading tensorflow-2.9.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (511.7 MB)
remote:        Collecting h11>=0.8
remote:          Downloading h11-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
remote:        Collecting click>=7.0
remote:          Downloading click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
remote:        Collecting asgiref>=3.4.0
remote:          Downloading asgiref-3.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
remote:        Collecting typing-extensions
remote:          Downloading typing_extensions-4.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests
remote:          Downloading requests-2.28.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
remote:        Collecting opt-einsum>=2.3.2
remote:          Downloading opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
remote:        Collecting flatbuffers>=1.12
remote:          Downloading flatbuffers-2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
remote:        Collecting gast>=0.2.1
remote:          Downloading gast-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.1.1
remote:          Downloading Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
remote:        Collecting libclang>=9.0.1
remote:          Downloading libclang-14.0.1-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (14.5 MB)
remote:        Collecting grpcio<2.0,>=1.24.3
remote:          Downloading grpcio-1.46.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.4 MB)
remote:        Collecting tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8
remote:          Downloading tensorboard-2.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 MB)
remote:        Collecting astunparse>=1.6.0
remote:          Downloading astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
remote:        Collecting protobuf>=3.9.2
remote:          Downloading protobuf-4.21.1-cp37-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (407 kB)
remote:        Collecting keras<2.9,>=2.8.0rc0
remote:          Downloading keras-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
remote:        Collecting six>=1.12.0
remote:          Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0
remote:          Downloading termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz (3.9 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting absl-py>=0.4.0
remote:          Downloading absl_py-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (123 kB)
remote:        Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.1
remote:          Downloading google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
remote:        Collecting tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem>=0.23.1
remote:          Downloading tensorflow_io_gcs_filesystem-0.26.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.4 MB)
remote:        Collecting h5py>=2.9.0
remote:          Downloading h5py-3.7.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (4.5 MB)
remote:        Collecting tf-estimator-nightly==2.8.0.dev2021122109
remote:          Downloading tf_estimator_nightly-2.8.0.dev2021122109-py2.py3-none-any.whl (462 kB)
remote:        Collecting wrapt>=1.11.0
remote:          Downloading wrapt-1.14.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (77 kB)
remote:        Collecting anyio<5,>=3.4.0
remote:          Downloading anyio-3.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (80 kB)
remote:        Collecting tqdm
remote:          Downloading tqdm-4.64.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
remote:        Collecting filelock
remote:          Downloading filelock-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
remote:        Collecting beautifulsoup4
remote:          Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
remote:        Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15
remote:          Downloading Werkzeug-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (224 kB)
remote:        Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1
remote:          Downloading google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
remote:        Collecting markdown>=2.6.8
remote:          Downloading Markdown-3.3.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
remote:        Collecting google-auth<3,>=1.6.3
remote:          Downloading google_auth-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
remote:        Collecting tensorboard-data-server<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
remote:          Downloading tensorboard_data_server-0.6.1-py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (4.9 MB)
remote:        Collecting tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0
remote:          Downloading tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (781 kB)
remote:        Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
remote:          Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
remote:        Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
remote:          Downloading urllib3-1.26.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
remote:        Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
remote:          Downloading idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
remote:        Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
remote:          Downloading certifi-2022.5.18.1-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
remote:        Collecting gast>=0.2.1
remote:          Downloading gast-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
remote:        Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.10.0,>=2.9.0rc0
remote:          Downloading tensorflow_estimator-2.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (438 kB)
remote:        Collecting tensorflow>=1.9.0
remote:          Downloading tensorflow-2.9.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (511.7 MB)
remote:          Downloading tensorflow-2.8.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (498.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.9,>=2.8
remote:          Downloading tensorflow_estimator-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (462 kB)
remote:        Collecting protobuf>=3.9.2
remote:          Downloading protobuf-3.19.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
remote:        Collecting sniffio>=1.1
remote:          Downloading sniffio-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
remote:        Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4
remote:          Downloading rsa-4.8-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
remote:        Collecting cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0
remote:          Downloading cachetools-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
remote:          Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0
remote:          Downloading requests_oauthlib-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
remote:        Collecting soupsieve>1.2
remote:          Downloading soupsieve-2.3.2.post1-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
remote:        Collecting PySocks!=1.5.7,>=1.5.6
remote:          Downloading PySocks-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
remote:          Downloading pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
remote:        Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0
remote:          Downloading oauthlib-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (151 kB)
remote:        Building wheels for collected packages: gdown, termcolor
remote:          Building wheel for gdown (pyproject.toml): started
remote:          Building wheel for gdown (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for gdown: filename=gdown-4.4.0-py3-none-any.whl size=14759 sha256=7708c4f7156a089f3fc5fc4488a952096a5a55641ba3eb077fbe30557bad88b9
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-gs7e9o2q/wheels/03/0b/3f/6ddf67a417a5b400b213b0bb772a50276c199a386b12c06bfc
remote:          Building wheel for termcolor (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for termcolor (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for termcolor: filename=termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl size=4848 sha256=1d47aa236c647ae87a51f34c01fb6c879088c2d0af3e04cd7a949a4b8b0ae977
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-gs7e9o2q/wheels/a1/49/46/1b13a65d8da11238af9616b00fdde6d45b0f95d9291bac8452
remote:        Successfully built gdown termcolor
remote:        Installing collected packages: tf-estimator-nightly, termcolor, tensorflow-estimator, tensorboard-plugin-wit, pyasn1, libclang, keras, flatbuffers, wrapt, werkzeug, urllib3, typing-extensions, tqdm, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, tensorboard-data-server, soupsieve, sniffio, six, rsa, PySocks, pyasn1-modules, protobuf, Pillow, oauthlib, numpy, markdown, idna, h11, gunicorn, gast, filelock, click, charset-normalizer, certifi, cachetools, asgiref, absl-py, uvicorn, torch, requests, pydantic, opt-einsum, opencv-python, keras-preprocessing, h5py, grpcio, google-pasta, google-auth, beautifulsoup4, astunparse, anyio, torchvision, starlette, requests-oauthlib, google-auth-oauthlib, gdown, fastapi, tensorboard, tensorflow-cpu, tensorflow, retina-face
remote:        Successfully installed Pillow-8.4.0 PySocks-1.7.1 absl-py-1.1.0 anyio-3.6.1 asgiref-3.5.2 astunparse-1.6.3 beautifulsoup4-4.11.1 cachetools-5.2.0 certifi-2022.5.18.1 charset-normalizer-2.0.12 click-8.1.3 fastapi-0.78.0 filelock-3.7.1 flatbuffers-2.0 gast-0.5.3 gdown-4.4.0 google-auth-2.7.0 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.6 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.46.3 gunicorn-20.1.0 h11-0.13.0 h5py-3.7.0 idna-3.3 keras-2.8.0 keras-preprocessing-1.1.2 libclang-14.0.1 markdown-3.3.7 numpy-1.22.4 oauthlib-3.2.0 opencv-python-4.5.4.58 opt-einsum-3.3.0 protobuf-3.19.4 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pydantic-1.9.1 requests-2.28.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.1 retina-face-0.0.12 rsa-4.8 six-1.16.0 sniffio-1.2.0 soupsieve-2.3.2.post1 starlette-0.19.1 tensorboard-2.8.0 tensorboard-data-server-0.6.1 tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.8.1 tensorflow-2.8.2 tensorflow-cpu-2.8.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.8.0 tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem-0.26.0 termcolor-1.1.0 tf-estimator-nightly-2.8.0.dev2021122109 torch-1.11.0+cpu torchvision-0.12.0+cpu tqdm-4.64.0 typing-extensions-4.2.0 urllib3-1.26.9 uvicorn-0.17.6 werkzeug-2.1.2 wrapt-1.14.1
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:  !     Compiled slug size: 826.6M is too large (max is 500M).
remote:  !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to lit-castle-78959.
remote:
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are installing both `pytorch` and `tensorflow` in the same slug.

Both libraries are known to be large and they are rarely deployed in the same slug.

Since they both aim to solve the same problem (neural networks/tensor computation), do you really need both? If yes, try to split your application and create two different slugs.

I am used to deploy slugs with either `torch==1.11.0+cpu` or `tensorflow-cpu==2.1.0`.

Comment: Even if only torch == 1.11.0 + cpu is used, it will be Compiled slug size: 844.3M is too large (max is 500M).

Comment: This CPU version of pytorch should be fine and can be deploy on free version Heroku (<500Mo).
For more installation details you can check:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59122860/10680282

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66944862/10680282