# Django app deployment on heroku compiled slug size is too large

Tags: python, django, heroku

So i am deploying my django application which consists on a reural network model used for fungus classification. The total files on the repo wheight like 100MB but i keep getting this error:

```
129 static files copied to '/tmp/build_dcf9fdff/hongOS_project/staticfiles'.
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:  !     Compiled slug size: 1.1G is too large (max is 500M).
remote:  !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: e8bac23bbcb75c7d2773ba8eecf5613182f0a4ac
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version e8bac23bbcb75c7d2773ba8eecf5613182f0a4ac
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to hongos-heroku.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/hongos-heroku.git
 ! [remote rejected] develop-heroku -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: fallo el push de algunas referencias a 'https://git.heroku.com/hongos-heroku.git'
```

What really annoys me is the part where it says:

```
129 static files copied to '/tmp/build_dcf9fdff/hongOS_project/staticfiles'.
```

I don't really get why it is doing that. But in case i can't use heroku, what do you recommend me to do? I am really desperate to be honest

This are all the dependencies installed:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.10.5
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.10.5
remote: -----> Installing pip 22.1.2, setuptools 60.10.0 and wheel 0.37.1
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting Django==4.0.6
remote:          Downloading Django-4.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting fastai==2.7.7
remote:          Downloading fastai-2.7.7-py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
remote:        Collecting fastbook==0.0.26
remote:          Downloading fastbook-0.0.26-py3-none-any.whl (719 kB)
remote:        Collecting fastcore==1.5.10
remote:          Downloading fastcore-1.5.10-py3-none-any.whl (68 kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
remote:        Collecting numpy==1.23.1
remote:          Downloading numpy-1.23.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting pandas==1.4.3
remote:          Downloading pandas-1.4.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.6 MB)
remote:        Collecting Pillow==9.2.0
remote:          Downloading Pillow-9.2.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
remote:        Collecting scikit-learn==1.1.1
remote:          Downloading scikit_learn-1.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (30.4 MB)
remote:        Collecting torch==1.12.0
remote:          Downloading torch-1.12.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (776.3 MB)
remote:        Collecting torchvision==0.13.0
remote:          Downloading torchvision-0.13.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (19.1 MB)
remote:        Collecting wasabi==0.9.1
remote:          Downloading wasabi-0.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
remote:        Collecting yarl==1.7.2
remote:          Downloading yarl-1.7.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (305 kB)
remote:        Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.4.1
remote:          Downloading asgiref-3.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
remote:        Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
remote:          Downloading sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests
remote:          Downloading requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
remote:        Collecting spacy<4
remote:          Downloading spacy-3.4.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (6.4 MB)
remote:        Collecting fastprogress>=0.2.4
remote:          Downloading fastprogress-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
remote:        Collecting scipy
remote:          Downloading scipy-1.8.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (42.2 MB)
remote:        Collecting packaging
remote:          Downloading packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
remote:        Collecting fastdownload<2,>=0.0.5
remote:          Downloading fastdownload-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyyaml
remote:          Downloading PyYAML-6.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (682 kB)
remote:        Collecting matplotlib
remote:          Downloading matplotlib-3.5.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.9 MB)
remote:        Collecting sentencepiece
remote:          Downloading sentencepiece-0.1.96-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
remote:        Collecting transformers
remote:          Downloading transformers-4.21.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)
remote:        Collecting graphviz
remote:          Downloading graphviz-0.20.1-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
remote:        Collecting datasets
remote:          Downloading datasets-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (365 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.1
remote:          Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
remote:        Collecting pytz>=2020.1
remote:          Downloading pytz-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
remote:        Collecting joblib>=1.0.0
remote:          Downloading joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306 kB)
remote:        Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
remote:          Downloading threadpoolctl-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
remote:        Collecting typing-extensions
remote:          Downloading typing_extensions-4.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
remote:        Collecting idna>=2.0
remote:          Downloading idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
remote:        Collecting multidict>=4.0
remote:          Downloading multidict-6.0.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (114 kB)
remote:        Collecting six>=1.5
remote:          Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
remote:          Downloading murmurhash-1.0.7-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (21 kB)
remote:        Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
remote:          Downloading cymem-2.0.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (35 kB)
remote:        Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.38.0
remote:          Downloading tqdm-4.64.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
remote:        Collecting catalogue<2.1.0,>=2.0.6
remote:          Downloading catalogue-2.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
remote:        Collecting langcodes<4.0.0,>=3.2.0
remote:          Downloading langcodes-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (181 kB)
remote:        Collecting typer<0.5.0,>=0.3.0
remote:          Downloading typer-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
remote:        Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
remote:          Downloading preshed-3.0.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (128 kB)
remote:        Collecting spacy-loggers<2.0.0,>=1.0.0
remote:          Downloading spacy_loggers-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
remote:        Collecting pathy>=0.3.5
remote:          Downloading pathy-0.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
remote:        Collecting srsly<3.0.0,>=2.4.3
remote:          Downloading srsly-2.4.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (460 kB)
remote:        Collecting spacy-legacy<3.1.0,>=3.0.9
remote:          Downloading spacy_legacy-3.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
remote:        Collecting thinc<8.2.0,>=8.1.0
remote:          Downloading thinc-8.1.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (822 kB)
remote:        Collecting pydantic!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<1.10.0,>=1.7.4
remote:          Downloading pydantic-1.9.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting jinja2
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2
remote:          Downloading pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
remote:        Collecting charset-normalizer<3,>=2
remote:          Downloading charset_normalizer-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
remote:        Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
remote:          Downloading certifi-2022.6.15-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
remote:        Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
remote:          Downloading urllib3-1.26.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (139 kB)
remote:        Collecting xxhash
remote:          Downloading xxhash-3.0.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (211 kB)
remote:        Collecting fsspec[http]>=2021.11.1
remote:          Downloading fsspec-2022.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
remote:        Collecting huggingface-hub<1.0.0,>=0.1.0
remote:          Downloading huggingface_hub-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
remote:        Collecting aiohttp
remote:          Downloading aiohttp-3.8.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
remote:        Collecting responses<0.19
remote:          Downloading responses-0.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
remote:        Collecting dill<0.3.6
remote:          Downloading dill-0.3.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyarrow>=6.0.0
remote:          Downloading pyarrow-8.0.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (29.4 MB)
remote:        Collecting multiprocess
remote:          Downloading multiprocess-0.70.13-py310-none-any.whl (133 kB)
remote:        Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
remote:          Downloading kiwisolver-1.4.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.6 MB)
remote:        Collecting cycler>=0.10
remote:          Downloading cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0
remote:          Downloading fonttools-4.34.4-py3-none-any.whl (944 kB)
remote:        Collecting filelock
remote:          Downloading filelock-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
remote:        Collecting tokenizers!=0.11.3,<0.13,>=0.11.1
remote:          Downloading tokenizers-0.12.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (6.6 MB)
remote:        Collecting regex!=2019.12.17
remote:          Downloading regex-2022.7.25-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (765 kB)
remote:        Collecting smart-open<6.0.0,>=5.2.1
remote:          Downloading smart_open-5.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
remote:        Collecting blis<0.8.0,>=0.7.8
remote:          Downloading blis-0.7.8-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (10.2 MB)
remote:        Collecting click<9.0.0,>=7.1.1
remote:          Downloading click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
remote:        Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2
remote:          Downloading aiosignal-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1
remote:          Downloading frozenlist-1.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (157 kB)
remote:        Collecting async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3
remote:          Downloading async_timeout-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
remote:        Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
remote:          Downloading attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
```

Only torch library by itself weights like 800 MB but i need it for fastai, what can i do?

Comment: Check whether this helps to solve the issue.https://stackoverflow.com/q/59122308/13779320

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Check whether [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59122308/13779320) solves your problem.

Heroku states that The slug size limit can be increased, although we have seen that slug sizes above 1GB can cause a dyno to fail to boot.

We encourage you to keep your slug sizes under 500MB, increase requests can be made by creating a new ticket stating what you would like the limit to be raised to and will be considered on a case-by-case basis.

Refer [my-slug-size-is-too-large-how-can-i-make-it-smaller](https://help.heroku.com/KUFMEES1/my-slug-size-is-too-large-how-can-i-make-it-smaller) to know more details about this